# Linked server from SQL Server 2008 to Visual Foxpro not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to create a linked server to Visual FoxPro with this:

```
sp_addlinkedserver 'VFP','','MSDASQL',NULL,NULL,'DRIVER={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver}; SourceDB=d:\BORDCAB.dbf;SourceType=dbf;NULL'
```

and says it was created, but when I try:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(VFP, 'SELECT * FROM BORDCAB')
```

it takes several minutes and doesn't return any result or errors...

Does someone know what is wrong?

Edit: I can see the linked server in the sql server management studio, but if i right click over this linked server and click properties can´t see it.

Is the connection drivers the same for sql server and visual studio??, because i do it a very simple program to see the data of this dbf and Works fine with ODBC.

Comment: I think using this connection string can help: `Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=d:\BORDCAB.dbf;
Exclusive=No;Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;` ;).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but don´t solve the problem, stay all the time executing the qyuery

Comment: As a guess, Vfp drivers, ODBC as well as OleDB, are x86 32bit, so a "linked server" might work on an x86 MS "SQL Server" but not with an x64 version - I'd try a web search on keywords like "ms sql server linked server vfp 32bit 64bit"

Comment: Thanks for help, I solved re-installing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i do a backup of my DB, then i re-installed MSSQLSERVER, restored the database, and installed the oledb driver for visual FoxPro and now Works fine.